# Why isn't this selector working (Jquery and Asp.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net application. In the Default.aspx file I have this code.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

    <div id="chrome_ctrl_placeholder"></div>
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBox ID ="aspTech" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" runat="server" value="Technical" id="Technical" /> Technical<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" runat="server" value="Commercial" id="Commercial"/> Commercial<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" runat="server" value="HR" id="HR"/>  HR <br />
        <%--<li><input type="button" runat="server" value="Save" id="btnSave" /></li>--%>

        <button id="btnSave" >Save</button> 
        <button id="btnChecked" >Checked</button> 
        <button id="btnText">Text</button>
    </div>
```

and in the App.js File I have this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#btnChecked").click(function () {
    alert("Checking");

    if ($("#Technical").checked == true) {
        alert("Tech Checked");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Tech Not Checked");
    }
});
})
```

Theres a little more code but its not relevant.

When I run the code it builds fine, and when I click the btnChecked button it alerts out "Checking" but it never picks up if the checkbox with id "Technical" is checked, it always alerts out "Tech Not Checked". And what would the right code be to check if the ASP checkbox (with id aspTech) has been checked?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sence to use `$('input[name="checkBox"]').val()`?

Comment: You'll probably want to read up on [`Control.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) and [`Control.ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx). Controls with `runat="server"` don't typically keep their server-side IDs as-is for client-side. They often end up something like `id="PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_Technical"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#Technical")` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element. The `checked` property applies to DOM elements, not to jQuery objects.

Either use the jQuery equivalent:

```
if ($("#Technical").is(":checked")) {
}
```

Or access the DOM element wrapped by the jQuery object:

```
if ($("#Technical")[0].checked) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
$("#Technical").is(':checked')
```

or [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$("#Technical").prop('checked') === true
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are checking against server-side control in your jQuery code, you should refer the control using it's `ClientID`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#<%=btnChecked.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    alert("Checking");

    if ($("#<%=Technical.ClientID%>").checked == true) {
        alert("Tech Checked");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Tech Not Checked");
    }
});
})
```